# QtConcurrent blocks UI

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, qml

Since the `onClicked` Event of a Button blocks the UIThread and freezes it for a while i tried to outsource some heavy work into a `QtConcurrent` that is run in a registered cpp file. but somehow the ui is still blocked.

in the onClicked event i do the following

```
onClicked: {
    loadingIndicator.visible = true
    cppBackend.doHeavyWork()
}
```

In the cppBackend the heavywork is run in a Qtconcurrent

```
void doHeavyWork(){
    QtConcurrent::run([this] {
        parentMemberObject.heavyFunction()
        emit dismissLoadingIndicator();
    });
}
```

after that i catch the signal in the qml again and dismiss the loading indicator

```
cppBackend {
    onDismissLoadingIndicator: loadingIndicator.visible = false
}
```

for some reason when I do this the loadingIndicator doesn't even show up. If i pass a `QThreadPool` to my lambda that is executed in the `QtConcurrent` it shows up but it still does not update. It is still frozen after showing up.

**Interesting:** If i extend the runtime of my concurrent function drastically with e.g. a long lasting loop the loading indicator shows up immediately and is also updating without problems. could this be some prioritization problem? i should have enough cores to run the threads concurrent

Comment: Try liberally adding logging to each of these functions/blocks, and also to `parentMemberObject.heavyFunction()` and see in which order they get printed out. At least in C++ side, also print the thread id.

Comment: Also, might be helpful if you show the `parentMemberObject.heavyFunction()`. If it is too complex, replace it with some dummy test function, test that the issue still remains, and then add it to the question.